# use findViewById with string

Tags: android, textview

I am working in android,

In my application, I have a option to add TextViews.

I can have up to 5 TextViews with the Ids of - Number1, Number2, Number3, etc..

**I am setting the first ID directly in the main_activity.xml and the rest with a resources file**

```
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="Number2" />
    <item type="id" name="Number3" />
    <item type="id" name="Number4" />
    <item type="id" name="Number5" />
</resources>
```

I have the current number of textviews.

**I am looking for a good way to access the textview with only the current number of textviews.**

**What I mean is,**

**instead of doing**

```
switch (TextViewNumber) {
    case 2:
        findViewById(R.id.Number2);
        break;
    case 3:
        findViewById(R.id.Number3);
        break;
    case 4:
        findViewById(R.id.Number4);
        break;

    }
```

I want to use the number of TextViews (**TextViewNumber**) in some generic, with better performance way..

**I have the same issue when I set the TextViews:**

```
switch (TextViewNumber) {
    case 2:
        newTextView.setId(R.id.IngredientNumber2);
        break;
    case 3:
        newTextView.setId(R.id.IngredientNumber3);
        break;
    case 4:
        newTextView.setId(R.id.IngredientNumber4);
        break;

    }
```

**The Class That Handles Moving the Views:**

```
public class LayoutOrganizer {

    public static RelativeLayout.LayoutParams getRelativeLayoutParams(int TExtViewCount, TextView textView) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams myLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            myLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

            // this is where I need to access the view ID
            myLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, ViewID); 

        return myLayoutParams;
    }
 }
```

**any ideas for a better way to use the TextViewNumber??**

Comment: `int id = getResource().getIdentifier("IngredientNumber"+ TextViewNumber, "id", getPackageName());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```java
TextView textView = this.findViewById(this.getResources().getIdentifier("Number" + TextViewNumber, "id", this.getPackageName()));
```

Keep in mind that `Resources#getIdentifier(String, String, String)` can return 0, which is an invalid id.

Comment: thanks for your answer! it works fine in the MainActivity. the thing is that I have a class with static methods that handle moving some views when I add a textivew. in the method i am reffering to the views wit their ID's, and I can't use this code in classes other than the MainActivity. I edited my question witht the static methods

Comment: It depends what you are trying to do in your static method. You are not using either `TextViewCount` or `textView`. You can my above code before calling your static method, or add a `Context` argument to be able to access `getResources()`.

Comment: okay I'll try, anyway your answer for my original question was great so accepte answer it is!

Answer (score 0):

You could put them all into an array in the onCreate.

```
private ArrayList<TextView> textviews = new ArrayList<TextView>(textViewCount);    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    textViews.add(findViewById(R.id.Number1));
    textViews.add(findViewById(R.id.Number2));
    ...

    // Then access them using a number
    Textview textView2 = textViews.get(1);
}
```

Alternatively if they are all siblings in a parent view you could access them by they viewIndex using`parent.getChildAt(textViewIndex);`